# Parentheses not capturing c# regex groups

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Trying to extract the `name` and `id` from a string with the following code:

```
Regex.Matches
    "id: 123456, name: some dude",
    @"^id: (?<id>\d+), name: (?<name>[a-z]+(\s[a-z]+)?)"
);
```

However, the number of groups and captures is 1, and there are no named captures. What am I missing?

**Edit:** Found the answer (thanks everyone!) but for future reference, it turns out it's because I completely misunderstood the API and was accessing the matches wrong. I was doing stuff like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(matches.Count); // 1
foreach( Group g in matches ) {
    Console.WriteLine(g.Captures.Count); //1
    foreach( Capture c in g.Captures ) {
        Console.WriteLine(c.Value); // The whole string
    }
}
```

But now I know better!

Comment: `^id:\s(?<id>\d+),\sname:\s(?<name>[\w\s]+)` ?

Comment: Works fine... Can you please show how you try to access the groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works just fine

```
String sample = "id: 123456, name: some dude";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^id: (?<id>\d+), name: (?<name>[a-z]+(\s[a-z]+)?)");

Match match = regex.Match(sample);

if (match.Success)
{
   Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["id"].Value);
   Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["name"].Value);
}
```

And when .Net Fiddle works again [you can demo it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z3kaUP)

---

**For Completness**

[Regex.Match Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Searches the specified input string for the first occurrence of the
>   regular expression specified in the Regex constructor.

[Regex.Matches Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Searches an input string for all occurrences of a regular expression
>   and returns all the matches.

[Match.Groups Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets a collection of groups matched by the regular expression. Groups
>   can then be retrieved from the `GroupCollection` object

[GroupCollection.Item Property (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hchbwda2(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Enables access to a member of the collection by string index.
>   `GroupName` can be either the name of a capturing group that is defined
>   by the `(?<name>)` element in a regular expression, or the string
>   representation of the number of a capturing group that is defined by a
>   grouping construct

Answer (score 2):

There is probably something wrong with the way you look for matches as your regex look ok:

```
Regex.Matches(
    "id: 123456, name: some dude",
    @"^id: (?<id>\d+), name: (?<name>[a-z]+(\s[a-z]+)?)"
)[0].Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(2).Select(x => new {x.Name, x.Value})
```

Produces:

```
    Name  Value
    id    123456 
    name  some dude
```

If you just need particular one - `Regex.Matches(...)[0].Groups[2]` or `.Groups["id"]`.

Note that your code uses `Matches` that returns all matches, if you just expect single match - use `Match` as shown in [Michael Randall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1612975/michael-randall) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49185460/477420)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Match` instead of `Matches`, and use non-capturing groups `(?:)` in your regex.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1uHgYY/1)

```
String input = "id: 123456, name: some dude";

var output = Regex.Match(input, @"^id: (?<id>\d+), name: (?<name>.+)");

System.Console.WriteLine(output.Groups["id"]);
System.Console.WriteLine(output.Groups["name"]);
```

Output:

```
123456 
some dude
```